# Git pull not working in windows, fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: windows, git, github

In windows when I try git pull origin master, I get this error. But it works when I try from Git Bash.

```
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

.

This error comes when I try from windows command prompt.

Comment: do you have a dual boot ? or did you clone the repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that when run outside of Git Bash, `git` can't find your private key for the repository you are trying to access.

Run `echo $HOME` in Git Bash and `set HOME` in Windows command prompt and compare results.

Comment: You are right. Thanks, now it works fine. I setup the proper value for HOME.